# Dynamically changing of date

Tags: c#, datetime

This Current Date and time, but I want to have time dynamically changeable like system Time:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Current Date:" + " " + t.ToString("MMMM dddd dd, yyyy")+"  " +"current Time:" +" " +t.ToString("hh:mm ss tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

On your winform, add a *Timer Control* and a *Label Control*.

In the *Form Load Event* add the code

```
yourTimer.Start();
```

In the Property sheet of the Timer Control, change the *Interval Property* to 1000.

Add the *Timer Tick Event*

```
private void yourTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want the ToolStripStatusLabel text to change with the time. For that, you'll need to have a timer callback. Add a Timer to your form and in its Elapsed handler, set the text to the current time, like you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Else you can set the time once from the server side and keep changing the tooltip value from Javascript. In this case you don't have to go to the server side again and again :)

Comment: He is talking about a winforms application here

Answer (score 0):

Just some more information

In your code:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Current Date:" + " " 
                            + t.ToString("MMMM dddd dd, yyyy")
                            + "  " + "current Time:" 
                            + " " + t.ToString("hh:mm ss tt");
```

The current date is evaluated only once.
That is to say, DateTime t = DateTime.Now stores the current date in t and this value is never updated again.

So even if you use 't' a hundred times, it will always have the value that was assigned to it.

Like astander pointed out, you need to update it every second or so.

A suggestion:

Instead of using "somestring" + "someotherstring" + "yetanotherstring" you should
use String.Format instead. For example (based on the code by astander)

```
private void yourTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourLabel.Text = String.Format("Current Date: {0}",  
                                  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
}
```